# JavaScript - How to handle the Daylight Savings in Europe

Tags: javascript, dst

I am new to `javascript` and I am trying to `console.log` some values based on the business hours and off business hours in `Europe`

My Business hours are as below:

> Monday-Thursday (08:00 - 16:00) & Friday 08:00-12:30

My Off-Business hours are as below:

> Everything else apart from the business hours

Everything looks good but I am having a hard time handling the Day Light Savings.

According to the laws, the `last Sunday in March and October` are the breakpoints where the Daylight savings on and off.

Here's my code snippet:

```
function businessOrOffBusinessHours() {
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  
  var hours = date.getUTCHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  
  console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset())
  if (date.getTimezoneOffset() === 60) {
    // Daylight savings
    hours += 1;
    console.log("daylight savings...")
  }

  hours += 2;  
  
  console.log(hours+":"+minutes)
 
  if ((day >= 1 && day <= 4 && hours >= 8 && hours < 16) || (day === 5 && hours >= 8 && (hours <= 12 && minutes < 30))) {
    console.log("Business Hours");
  } else {
    console.log("Off Business Hours");
  }
}

businessOrOffBusinessHours()
```

The problem with above code is that even if I initialise the `Date()` object with a value like `Date("2023-06-10T00:00:00Z")` where the date falls exactly within the Daylight Savings window (i.e. `last Sunday in March and October`), I would still get the `getTimezoneOffset()` equals to `0`

Can someone help me with this?

**PS: I don't want to use any other third party javascript libraries or frameworks, I appreciate the solution to be fully in vanilla**

Comment: DST is included in Date object local values, you don't need to check that. On the other hand, DST isn't applied to UTC at all.

Comment: @Teemu, so my solution is correct and nothing to worry about?

Comment: I don't know, are you getting expected final results?

Comment: Hi @Teemu the expected result I get is the result I have put on my question. `DST is included in Date object local values` ---> Did you mean the value I put or the default values come with `Date()` object? If it is the latter, can you point me to a documentation that says it?

Comment: When you create a date object with Date constructor, the locale representations of the created object include DST. See ex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset#varied_results_in_daylight_saving_time_dst_regions